# Full width HTML5 Video issue

Tags: css, html, video, width

I am looking for a way to do a full width (but not full height) HTML5 video.

Something like what the background-cover CSS for images would let me do.

Example:

http://photohack.rs.af.cm

Where the image bar below the header would be replaced with a full width video background.

Width 100% and setting the height do not work, since the video is auto-scaled, and not full width.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases its a simple fix.

```
video {
   max-width: 640px /* cannot exceed this width */
   max-height: 390px /* cannot exceed this height */
   width: 100% /* 640px or less depending on size of viewport */
   height: auto /* automatically calculates height from via above values */
}
```

Always! Always use percents when dealing with full width videos, responsive design and mobile. The only time it is okay to use pixels is when defining the `max-height` and `max-width`properties.